# open bravo erp + informations

Tags: open-source, openbravo

I'm expect to install community edition of openbravo.but i can't find some information.
I want to know no of concurrent users limits of community versions, no of register
users andany restrictions of this system also.

Many thanks for any help..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openbravo community edition have no limit of concurrent users but some of the premium features like require a Professional edition.

```
Core - Core: Included in the core, licensed under Openbravo Public License

Open Source Extension Module - Extension Module: Same as core from licensing and support perspective.

Premium Feature (zero cost) - Premium Feature: Same as core from licensing and support perspective, requires a Professional Edition or Basic Edition to use, zero cost

Commercial Extension Module (zero cost) - Commercial Extension Module: Requires a Professional Edition or Basic Edition to install and use, licensed under Openbravo Commercial License, zero cost for Professional Edition

Commercial Extension Module - Commercial Extension Module: Requires a Professional Edition or Basic Edition to install and use, licensed under Openbravo Commercial License, at additional cost
```

Please have a look at following URL for details,

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP/Roadmap